# Face detection like seen on facebook

Tags: media

As we see in facebook, that it can detect & tag persons within a picture. Is there any way to achieve this from Drupal? any module exist?

The main purpose is to verify each user account- so everybody has only one account. Lots of country people don't have any National ID/passport. So, how can we trace their unique identification? Mobile number is a way, bt one person can have multiple numbers.

OR, is there any way, we can scan finger print as iphone6 has that built-in function........

I know i'm asking for too much,,bt I already need that kinda stuff in job :(

Any suggestions are welcome .....please

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that level of security using facial recognition in a site like this. Even if you could gain control over a webcam for example, someone could just use a picture of someone else when registering a duplicate account

Answer (score 3):

I didn't think there was a module, but I found one. Take a look at [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/face_detection). From the project page:

> Face Detection module uses the [jQuery Facedetection](https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection) library to provide
>   an image viewer jQuery plugin.
>
> It only has been tested on Chrome, Firefox 3-8, IE 9

Comment: thanks for your answers. I know about this module. but this module mainly focusing on faces, but not taking any actions. like I can't tag people, it can't compare photo data to say, is this guy Bob?

https://www.drupal.org/node/910142#comment-5241506  has spoken about the same needs. Can we have someone who can speak of codes :3 ? Please.......

It can make the Drupal way to smart than any other CMS too :)